# Should I pass the object in or build it in the constructor?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

Perhaps this doesn't really matter, but I have a hunch I should 'pass in the object', but I'm not sure why.

### Situation

I have some `Record` objects that are being created by reading a text file (e.g. a CSV file). One of the fields defines possible actions to perform on this record.

For example:

```
class Action:
    def __init__(self, create, update, delete):
        self.create = create
        self.update = update
        self.delete = delete

    @staticmethod
    def parse_from_string(actions):
        return Action('c' in actions, 'u' in actions, 'd' in actions)
```

### Which of these two is better design?

```
class Record1:
    def __init__(self, actions_string, name, ...etc):
        self.action = Actions.parse_from_string(actions_string)
        ...

class Record2:
    def __init__(self, actions, name, ...etc):
        self.action = actions
```

With the difference in their use being:

```
action_string, name_string,... = read_details_from_file()

record1 = Record1(action_string, name_string, ...)

# vs.
actions_obj = Actions.parse_from_string(actions_string)
record2 = Record2(actions_obj, name_string, ... )
```

I think I am leaning to the second model, but I don't know why? Also, should I enforce that the object passed to the `Record2` constructor is of the correct type?

Comment: The `Action` object should be a parameter of the `Record.__init__`, to reduce the coupling between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good reason your spidey-sense is pointing you toward the second design: it better [separates concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Reducing dependency improves composability, reusability, and testability.

Comment: Cool, I thought so. Thanks

Comment: [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) strikes me as a more obviously applicable principle here, compared to Separation of Concerns; but I suppose that DI is just one manner of SoC.